# Loop through tableview Cells to see if UIImageView on cell is .hidden or not

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a uitableview and i have a custom cell with an imageView on it. The imageView is already populated with an image, but its `.hidden` property is set to `YES`. which means when the tableView is present, all of the cells images are hiding. In the app, you may set the images on/off. This is just a little information. My problem is that i need to loop through the tableViewCells and see if there are any images hidden or not.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I try to loop through the cells.

```
    BOOL cellImageViewsAreHidden = YES;

for (UITableViewCell *myCell in tableView.visibleCells) {

    if (self.cell.alert.hidden == NO) {

        cellImageViewsAreHidden = NO;

        break;
    }
    else{
        cellImageViewsAreHidden = YES;
    }
}

if (cellImageViewsAreHidden == NO) {
    NSLog(@"They are visible");
}

else{
    NSLog(@"they are hidden");
}
```

But this unfortunately only `NSLogs` `"they are hidden"`. It won't `NSLog` the correct text, even when there is an image visible. Any help, or suggestions are very appreciated!

Comment: Where have you written this code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually check the cell in the loop and not only the cell that is a property of your class by replacing

```
if (self.cell.alert.hidden == NO) {
```

with

```
if (myCell.alert.hidden == NO) {
```

Anyway, the correct way would be to store the state of the imageView in your data model. You'll need it there anyway, because you should reuse cells

Comment: thanks for the reply. How can i store the state of the image view into a data model? I know how to do this in core data/nsuserdefaults but i dont think it would work correctly. Thanks again!

Comment: the most simple way would be a NSMutableSet where you store all the indexPaths of the cells that show the imageView. If you use [imageView setHidden:NO], add the indexPath of that cell to the set, if you use [imageView setHidden:YES], remove that indexPath from the set. Then you will always have the indexPath of the cells that show the imageView in the set.

Comment: oh, great sounds like it should work. It seems better than the way im doing it now! haha Thank you Matthias! :)

Comment: one more question... What is the difference if i use a NSMutableSet as opposed to using a NSMutableArray? THank you@

Comment: a NS(Mutable)Set does not have an order. It has only distinct objects in it. It makes sure that objects that return YES for isEqual: are only one time in the set. E.g. if you  add three indexPaths, for the first row in the first section (0,0), to the set, there will only be one indexPath (0,0) actually in the set. That makes the whole thing more efficient if you use `containsObject:` and `removeObject:` often. [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Sets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000136-SW3)

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you create a custom object for tht table cell and keep a status for it.
Which means create a custom object with the details of tht table cell, create a bool value to hold the status whether the images apeared or not,

Assume user have off images on app. then ste tht property to false.
If not true. 
thn u dont have to play with the tableview properties. u will have more control.